# Building minigame in JQuery (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making a set of minigames for my major project, with this minigame I have being following the same method from a previous minigame that I built before.

In my previous minigame I only had one PuzzleContainer but in this one I'm making now has four. Ever since I added three more PuzzleContainers the code doesn't seem to work. Have I done something wrong in my scipting? Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

This is my code for the minigame I am currently working on.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 //speech
 var progress = 0;
 var txt;
 $('#complete, #speech').hide();
 
 function eventHandler() {
  switch (progress) {
   case 0:
    txt = "Complete";
    break;
   case 1:
    txt = "Move on to the next minigame";
    $('#speech').click(function(){
     window.location.href="minigame8.html";
    });
    break;
   }
   progress++;
   $('#speech').html(txt);
  }
  
  $('#speech').click(eventHandler);
 
 // Sortable //

 $('#puzzleContainer1', '#puzzleContainer2', '#puzzleContainer3', '#puzzleContainer4').sortable({
  update: function() {
   var userPieces = '';
   $('#puzzleContainer1 li', '#puzzleContainer2 li', '#puzzleContainer3 li', '#puzzleContainer4 li').each(function() {
    userPieces += $(this).attr('data');
   })
   checkResult(userPieces);
  }
 });
 $('#puzzleContainer1', '#puzzleContainer2', '#puzzleContainer3', '#puzzleContainer4').disableSelection();
 
 //shows the "Enterpassword once pieces are all correctly aligned
 function checkResult(userPieces) {
  if (userPieces == '1234' && '12345' && '123456') {
   $("#complete").show(0,function() {
    eventHandler()
    $('#speech').show();
   });
  }
 }
 
});
```

```css
#puzzleContainer1 {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 5;
 top: 10px;
 left: 130px;
 list-style-type: none;
}

#puzzleContainer2 {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 5;
 top: 75px;
 left: 130px;
 list-style-type: none;
}

#puzzleContainer3 {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 5;
 top: 140px;
 left: 130px;
 list-style-type: none;
}

#puzzleContainer4 {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 5;
 top: 205px;
 left: 130px;
 list-style-type: none;
}

ul, menu, dir {
 display: block;
}

.piece{
 z-index: 5;
 float: left;
 margin: 0 10px 0 0;
 padding: 0;
}

li {
 display: list-item;
 text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
}

#complete {
 position: absolute;
 width: 105px;
 height: 25px;
 top: 240px;
 left: 289px;
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
 font-size: 20px;
 padding: 10px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 5px;
 border-color: white;
 z-index:5;
}

#speech {
 position: absolute;
 width: 655px;
 height: 100px; 
 top: 330px;
 left: 15px;
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
 font-size: 25px;
 padding: 10px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 5px;
 border-color: white;
 z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>MAS340</title>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
//javascript goes here
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="stage">
  <ul id="puzzleContainer1" class="ui-sortable">
   <li class="piece" data="4"><img src="images/puzzle6/puzzleContainer1/L.png">4</li>
   <li class="piece" data="1"><img src="images/puzzle6/puzzleContainer1/redF.png">1</li>
   <li class="piece" data="2"><img src="images/puzzle6/puzzleContainer1/A.png">2</li>
   <li class="piece" data="5"><img src="images/puzzle6/puzzleContainer1/E.png">5</li>
   <li class="piece" data="3"><img src="images/puzzle6/puzzleContainer1/B.png">3</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="puzzleContainer2" class="ui-sortable">
   <li class="piece" data="3"><img src="images/puzzle6/puzzleContainer2/S.png">3</li>
   <li class="piece" data="2"><img src="images/puzzle6/puzzleContainer2/U.png">2</li>
   <li class="piece" data="4"><img src="images/puzzle6/puzzleContainer2/T.png">4</li>
   <li class="piece" data="1"><img src="images/puzzle6/puzzleContainer2/redR.png">1</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="puzzleContainer3" class="ui-sortable">
   <li class="piece" data="3"><img src="images/puzzle6/puzzleContainer3/A.png">3</li>
   <li class="piece" data="2"><img src="images/puzzle6/puzzleContainer3/N.png">2</li>
   <li class="piece" data="4"><img src="images/puzzle6/puzzleContainer3/B.png">4</li>
   <li class="piece" data="6"><img src="images/puzzle6/puzzleContainer3/E.png">6</li>
   <li class="piece" data="1"><img src="images/puzzle6/puzzleContainer3/redE.png">1</li>
   <li class="piece" data="5"><img src="images/puzzle6/puzzleContainer3/L.png">5</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="puzzleContainer4" class="ui-sortable">
   <li class="piece" data="1"><img src="images/puzzle6/puzzleContainer4/redE.png">1</li>
   <li class="piece" data="4"><img src="images/puzzle6/puzzleContainer4/O.png">4</li>
   <li class="piece" data="3"><img src="images/puzzle6/puzzleContainer4/H.png">3</li>
   <li class="piece" data="2"><img src="images/puzzle6/puzzleContainer4/C.png">2</li>
  </ul>
  <input id="password" type="text" style="display: block;">
  <button id="submit" style="display: block;">Enter Password</button>
  <div id="complete">ACCEPTED</div>
  <div id="speech"></div>
 </div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a problem with your selector. Try to select  puzzle containers like this:

```
$('#puzzleContainer1, #puzzleContainer2, #puzzleContainer3, #puzzleContainer4')
```

Comment: thnx for the help, now i can drag the blocks around, I also remembered to hid the #password and #submit, and trying to implement to have #password and #submit show when I correctly have the blocks in order, I have a feeling it has something to do with if (userPieces === '1234' && '12345' && '123456')

Comment: You should google or check on stackoverflow how to make an if statement with multiple conditions in Javascript. 

Anyway it seems you actually wanted to check if userPieces is equal '1234' OR '12345' OR '12345) then do smth.. You can do this like this: if (userPieces == '1234' || userPieces == '12345' || userPieces == '123456').